# Python requests xml: xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token):

Tags: python, xml, python-requests, xmltodict

I have a problem with parsing a XML with xmltodict. This method works on other XML-files online, but now I'm getting this error: "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token):"

What is going wrong here, and how can I fix/work around it?

```
import requests
import xmltodict

metadataxml = "https://nedlasting.geonorge.no/geonorge/Tjenestefeed_daglig.xml"

md_response = requests.get(metadataxml, stream=True)
md_data = md_response.text

xml = xmltodict.parse(md_data)
```

Comment: A) I’d expect you to parse `md_response.content` not the text version, and b) Have you actually looked at the response content (or whatever you parse) because it presumably _isn’t_ xml?

Comment: Changing to md_response.content solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing response.text to response.content seemed to solve the issue.

```
metadataxml = "https://nedlasting.geonorge.no/geonorge/Tjenestefeed_daglig.xml"

md_response = requests.get(metadataxml, stream=True)
md_data = md_response.text

xml = xmltodict.parse(md_data)
```